# Backup software with encryption and suitable for network drives

Tags: windows, backup, encryption, cloud-storage

I'm looking for Windows backup software (better free or open source) with following features:

- creates full & incremental backup copies
- allows to include different manually picked folders in a backup set
- supports local hard drives
- works well with network drives (including emulated drives through Netdrive or Expandrive)
- supports encryption for both data and file names, or at least mangles file names to something cryptic
- shows exactly what it is doing - which while is being backed up at the moment etc.
- provides tweakable settings for "control freaks"
- is able to browse the backup fast, even if it is on remote drive (I guess, it should store the file list separately instead of actually trying to enumerate all files on the drive)
- is able to resume in case if I turn off or hibernate the computer while backup is in progress
- scheduling is good but not mandatory, if only I can launch the program through command line from Windows Task Scheduler
- it would be great to have some verification option (checksums etc.) to check if the backup is fine
- it would be great if during 1:1 mirror backup, the program showed me a list of files which were deleted in the original dataset and asked me which files I want to delete in the backup
- it would be great to have Google Drive support out-of-the-box, but I can work around that using Netdrive or Expandrive, as long as the program works well with network drives

Long story:

I want to back up my ~100GB of data to both my external SATA drive and to Google Drive. Later I might start using Google Cloud Storage (Nearline, most probably) when/if it becomes available for natural persons because currently for my country Google says:

> This service can only be used for business or commercial reasons.

Of course, I don't want to store all my data on Google Drive unencrypted, and I'd like also to encrypt (or at least mangle) file names.

At first I tried to use all-in-one solutions like CloudBerry, but it turned out that it does not support encryption for Google Drive (but maybe it will in the future). Also I tried Arq for Windows, but it is too basic for my needs and sometimes it gets really slow for no apparent reason.

So I decided to stop looking for all-in-one solutions and installed Netdrive to mount Google Drive as a network drive.

Then I tried Cobian Backup, but it does not encrypt file names.

Next I tried Areca Backup and it works good, encrypts data, changes file names, shows complete action log live etc., but it is really slooooow with network drives. I guess, it's because of complex backup logic with transactions and what not. Maybe I could speed it up by backing up everything to a hard drive and then manually uploading to Google, but I'd like to find out if I have some other options.

Now I'm trying Comodo Backup. It was fast and offered a simple XOR encryption which is good enough to just obfuscate most of my data. But it failed to browse files on backup - it showed a popup with "Please wait to load information..." and then silently closed it without any errors and did not mount the backup. I guess, it does not work reliably with network shares.

Comment: You can try [Bacula](http://bacula.org/) or [URBackup](http://www.urbackup.org/). May be you might need to trade off on some features and decide. Commercial products might come for price with specific plugins. This [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/awesome-backup-software-for-linux-unix-osx-windows-systems/) will help you with additional insights.

Comment: Actually Cobian Backup 11 Gravity is able to encrypt file names if you use 7zip compression not zip. See options-> compression -> 7zip tab.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that, but thus far I have seen all those compression based backups fail to load their filelist in cases when I want to browse the archive on the network drive.